# Calling one method and getting result in different method in Applescript

Tags: variables, methods, scope, applescript

I'm trying to return the value of a variable declared in one method and get that result in another (from where it was called). I'm a new programmer and have looked through the scoping documents on the Apple site. I'm including some (made up) code below to show what I'm trying to do. I appreciate any help I can get. Thank you in advance.

```
on first_method()
    set bob to "This is the variable I wish to return"
    return bob
end first_method

on second_method()
    first_method()
end second_method
```

If I just call first_method() (from outside the second_method), it works fine. But I'm not able to get the value to return from within the second_method. I understand that it is a local variable. But I thought that it would be possible to return the result of the last argument and pass it back to where it was originally called. Is this incorrect? Is there any way to do what I'm attempting to pull off?

I realize this is probably really easy and I'm just demonstrating my own stupidity for not being able to find the answer. But I would really appreciate any help I could get in seeing the answer. I promise to repay the kindness someday, when I'm more experienced.

Thank you.

Comment: Your script snippet works for me - the second_method() does return the results of the first_method() call (although you would normally use an explicit return statement to avoid misunderstandings).  Or are you taking about the variable 'bob' instead of its contents?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? You're code works perfectly. The value you return needs to be assigned to a variable maybe that's the thing you overlooked.

```
second_method()

on first_method()
    set bob to "This is the variable I wish to return"
    return bob
end first_method

on second_method()
    set bob to first_method()
    display dialog bob --just to show you that it works
end second_method
```

Comment: Thank you, very much. I warned you I was a noob! I really appreciate the help.